# Dividing by a number based on cell answers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet where users will answer the field with a "Y" or an "N" value.

I then calculate the percentage of "Y" answers. Recently, users have been putting in the value of "N/A". We would like to exclude "N/A" answers from the formula. You can, from the image below, that the "N/A" value is being included in the denominator. In the formula below, I would like it to be 5/8. The current formula is calculating 5/10.

[image]

```
=(COUNTIF(B2:B11,"Y")/10
```

With this new logic to exclude "N/A", how would I do this?

I've tried something like this, but my results were not correct:

```
=(COUNTIF(B2:B11,"Y")/COUNTIF(B2:B11,"Y")+COUNTIF(B2:B11,"N"))
```

[image]

Comment: I have added another image, and clarification on what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question by using this formula:

```
=(COUNTIF(D2:D11,"Y")/COUNTIF(D2:D11,"<>N/A"))
```

Comment: Your only problem with the formula in the question was a misplaced parenthesis - this version should work `=COUNTIF(B2:B11,"Y")/(COUNTIF(B2:B11,"Y")+COUNTIF(B2:B11,"N"))`.....and is arguably more robust - that would still work if there are blanks in the range.....or somebody puts NA rather than N/A

Comment: @barryhoudini could you submit this as an answer. You are correct, yours is more robust.